# Spritekit silhouette effect when passing in front of object

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm working on a sprite kit game and I'm trying to create a particular silhouette lighting effect whenever objects pass in front of a particular object (in this case a red sun). I want anything in front of it to appear black, and everything else to appear as normal (so if an object is partially in front, only that part should be black).
But I'm not sure how to do it in an efficient way. I've tried playing around with different SKBlendModes but so far haven't had much success. The major challenge seems to be achieving the effect whilst preserving the colour of the sun behind.

I'm not sure if it's possible to achieve this with the existing SKBlendModes, or if something else will be required.

I've attached a diagram to illustrate what I'm going for and an image of the current best fit.

[image: Target]

[image: Best fit so far]

Comment: Are you coding in Swift or Obj-C? I may have a solution to this problem.

Comment: Objective-c. Should that make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the silhouette effect with an `SKCropNode`, a mask node, and a background node. An `SKCropNode` selectively mask pixels of the sprite nodes in its node tree. Here, it will provide the silhouette effect by hiding/revealing portions of a black circle.

First, create the following objects:

1. A shape node (yellow circle) with its `zPosition` set to -1
2. A sprite node (black circle) with the same size as the yellow one
3. A crop node (`SKCropNode`) and a mask node (`SKNode`)

Next,

1. Add the yellow circle at the center of the scene
2. Add the black sprite as a child of the crop node
3. Assign the mask node to the `maskNode` property of the crop node
4. Add the crop node at the center of the scene

Since the mask node currently has no children, the black circle will be completely hidden and the entire yellow circle beneath it will be visible. As we add sprites to the mask node, the pixels of the black circle that intersect with the sprite will be unmasked (shown in black), producing the silhouette effect.

All that's left is to add a "presentation" node that will be displayed when the mask node's sprite is outside of the black circle. The presentation node will mirror the mask node's sprite's position and rotation. This should be done in `didSimulatePhysics` to ensure that the presentation and mask-node sprites are synchronized after the physics and actions have been updated.

But wait...if the presentation node moves over the yellow circle, won't it eclipse the Sun? Not if we set its presentation node's `zPosition` to -2.

The following shows an implementation of the above:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, I'm amazed at how much effort you guys have gone to. I'm not sure how SKCropNode works internally, does this scale well? (say we have 700 sprites, and have little headway and all of them needed to have duplicates that are children of the maskNode)

Comment: I'm seeing 60 fps when I added 250 node pairs to the scene on an iPhone 6. I suggest you 1) reuse textures where possible, 2) only add the nodes to the mask when the sprite is near the Sun, and 3) remove sprites when they move off the screen.

Comment: And read this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit.html

Answer (score 2):

This problem was interesting to me, so I came up with a simple solution. It's not perfect nor does it scale very well, but the basics fulfill your need I believe and it may point others in the right direction.

I don't use any special SKBlendMode. Instead, I am using a duplicate object for the object which moves in front of the sun. This duplicate object is cropped using an SKCropNode with a duplicate of the sun as the maskNode. So, my node tree is as follows:

- SKSpriteNode (`sun`) (the white sun)
- SKSpriteNode (`object1`) (the rotating purple square with alpha 0.25)
- SKCropNode

  - maskNode: SKSpriteNode (`sunDuplicate = [sun copy]`)
  - SKSpriteNode (`object1duplicate`, same size as `object1` but with `[SKColor blackColor]`)

Inside the update method, align the duplicate with the original to ensure animation is properly forwarded.

```
- (void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
  self.object1duplicate.position = self.object1.position;
  self.object1duplicate.zRotation = self.object1.zRotation;
}
```

As I said, this doesn't scale very well since you'll manually have to add duplicate objects and keep track of them for each object moving in front of the sun object. Perhaps [SKShader](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShader_Ref/index.html) can be of more elegant use.

[image: Rendered output from an iPad Air]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I definitely won't be able to do this for all objects (we're already really pushing the limits on how many sprites we can have), but we might at least be able to do it with certain key objects.

Comment: I've done a bit of core OpenGL before, so have a vague idea how fragment shaders work, the thing I'm not sure about is how to access the colour of the pixel there (so say it's the fragment shader for a duplicate in front of the sun, and if the pixel is anything other than the sun colour, paint it black, otherwise, the paint it the sun colour). Basically I want the same information that SKBlendMode uses

Comment: Shouldn't the mask node be the copy of the square and the copy of the sun a child of the crop node?

Comment: @0x141E It can be, of course - would result in the same shapes being rendered. But if you want the square to be textured (as in OP's screenshot), you have to crop `object1duplicate` and not the `sunDuplicate`.

Comment: I'm not sure where the best place to say this is, but I looked into SKShaders and got my own fragment shaders working. In the absence of programmable blend modes or vertex shaders, it seems that there's no particularly good way to do this with SKShaders.